# DropDownList not accepting the SelectedIndex im trying to assign

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm having a hard time figuring this out and I hope you guys would help me.

I have a page called `Index.aspx` with a `DropDownList` that is a separate `UserControl` class (because it will be used in other pages). Here's the code for that:

UcSelecionarLocal.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="UcSelecionarLocal.ascx.cs" 
    Inherits="QuickMassage.uc.UcSelecionarLocal" %>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocais" runat="server" 
                  CssClass="span4 dropdown-toggle" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

UcSelecionarLocal.ascx.cs:

```
public partial class UcSelecionarLocal : UserControl {

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (!this.IsPostBack) {
          PreencherLocais();
      }
  }

  private void PreencherLocais() {
     ddlLocais.Items.Clear();
     ddlLocais.Items.Add(new ListItem("Selecione", "0"));
     ControleLocal controle = new ControleLocal();
     DataTable tab = controle.ListarLocais();
     foreach (DataRow row in tab.Rows) {
        ddlLocais.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["Descricao"].ToString(), 
                                         row["ID"].ToString()));
     }
  }
```

}

This control is placed in `Index.aspx` and loads its values correctly. The form that it's contained in, has the action set to `agendamentos.aspx`. When I change the `ddlist`, the page is submitted to the forms action page, as it should be.

On the other page the problems begin: I get the parameters posted to this page and one of them is the `ddlist` value. In the immediate window, I check the value and it's there, let's say that it is 1.

To make long story short, I have this code:

agendamentos.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DropDownList locais = ObterComponenteListaLocais();
        try {
            locais.SelectedIndex = 
              int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request["ucSelLocal$ddlLocais"]);
        }
```

While debugging, I see that `locais.SelectedIndex` is -1. After the assignment it remains -1. The page loads and then I change the `ddlist` value again to 2. When debugging the same code above, I see that the `locais.SelectedIndex` is now 1. Again, setting it to 2, as it would normally be, produces no effect. If I change the `ddlist` again to 3, the `SelectedIndex` becomes 2 and does not take the value 3.

In other words: the value of the index in a newly loaded page is the value of the page that was loaded before.

Could you guys help me?

Comment: you should set `selectedindex` after `dropdown list` has data ie, in `dropdownlist` `databound` event, you are trying to set value in `page_load` before `dropdown list` is bound with data

Comment: What does `ObterComponenteListaLocais` do?

Comment: @AnnL. Basically it returns the DropDownList, since it's inside a user control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the Page_Load event is firing in your page before the user control is loading. Do this:

```
public partial class UcSelecionarLocal : UserControl
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void PreencherLocais()
    {
        ddlLocais.Items.Clear();
        ddlLocais.Items.Add(new ListItem("Selecione", "0"));
        ControleLocal controle = new ControleLocal();
        DataTable tab = controle.ListarLocais();
        foreach (DataRow row in tab.Rows)
        {
            ddlLocais.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["Descricao"].ToString(), row["ID"].ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your aspx page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
            this.idOfYourUserControl.PreencherLocais();

        DropDownList locais = ObterComponenteListaLocais();
        try {
            locais.SelectedIndex = 
              int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request["ucSelLocal$ddlLocais"]);
        }
}
```

Also because your question is a little confusing, an important note is that Page_Load fires before data is captured from controls that post back data. So that's a bad place to get their information because it will be what it was previously. That's why you need to create a function that fires on something like a button click that will execute after the controls data have been loaded.